# Python ASCII codec can't encode character error during write to CSV

Tags: python, csv, url, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm not entirely sure what I need to do about this error. I assumed that it had to do with needing to add .encode('utf-8'). But I'm not entirely sure if that's what I need to do, nor where I should apply this.

**The error is:**

```
line 40, in <module>
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 1
7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**This is the base of my python script.**

```
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = \
'https://dummysite'

response = requests.get(url)

html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
list_of_cells = []
for cell in row.findAll('td'):
    text = cell.text.replace('[','').replace(']','')
    list_of_cells.append(text)
list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./test.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Location"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python 2.x CSV library is broken. You have three options. In order of complexity:

1. Edit: See below <strike>Use the fixed library https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv (`pip install unicodecsv`). Use as a drop-in replacement - Example:</strike>

   ```
   with open("myfile.csv", 'rb') as my_file:    
       r = unicodecsv.DictReader(my_file, encoding='utf-8')
   ```

2. Read the CSV manual regarding Unicode: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html (See examples at the bottom)
3. Manually encode each item as UTF-8:

   ```
   for cell in row.findAll('td'):
       text = cell.text.replace('[','').replace(']','')
       list_of_cells.append(text.encode("utf-8"))
   ```

**Edit, I found python-unicodecsv is also broken when reading UTF-16**. It complains about any `0x00` bytes.

Instead, use https://github.com/ryanhiebert/backports.csv, which more closely resembles Python 3 implementation and uses `io` module..

Install:

```
pip install backports.csv
```

Usage:

```
from backports import csv
import io

with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f):
```

Comment: oh wow didn't know that the CSV library was broken in python. Thank you very much! That's a huge help

Comment: Why isn't this voted up enough ? I've seem people using all kinds of workarounds for solving this, and honestly, none works better than simply using the "unicodecsv" module.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the csv library in python 2.
From the unicodecsv [project page](https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/)

> Python 2’s csv module doesn’t easily deal with unicode strings, leading to the dreaded “‘ascii’ codec can’t encode characters in position …” exception.

If you can, just install unicodecsv

`pip install unicodecsv`

```py
import unicodecsv

writer = unicodecsv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest option, in addition to [Alastair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554386/alastair-mccormack)'s excellent suggestions, to be using python3 instead of python 2. all it required in my script was to change `wb` in the `open` statement to simply `w` in [accordance with Python3's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34283957/493161).