# Unicode error ascii can't encode character

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode, encoding

I am trying to import a csv file in order to train my classifier but I keep receiving this error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "updateClassif.py", line 17, in <module>
myClassif = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 191, in __init__
    super(NLTKClassifier, self).__init__(train_set, feature_extractor, format, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.train_set = self._read_data(train_set, format)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 143, in _read_data
    return format_class(dataset, **self.format_kwargs).to_iterable()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\formats.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.data = [row for row in reader]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\textblob\unicodecsv\__init__.py", line 106, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe6' in position 55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The CSV file contains 1600000 lines of tweets so I believe some tweets contain special characters. I have tried saving it using open office as someone recommended but still the same result. I also tried using latin encoding but the same result. 
This is my code :

```
with codecs.open('tr.csv', 'r' ,encoding='latin-1') as fp:
myClassif = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")
```

This is the code from the library I am using:

```
def __init__(self, csvfile, fieldnames=None, restkey=None, restval=None,
                 dialect='excel', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict', *args,
                 **kwds):
        if fieldnames is not None:
            fieldnames = _stringify_list(fieldnames, encoding)
        csv.DictReader.__init__(self, csvfile, fieldnames, restkey, restval, dialect, *args, **kwds)
        self.reader = UnicodeReader(csvfile, dialect, encoding=encoding,
                                    errors=errors, *args, **kwds)
        if fieldnames is None and not hasattr(csv.DictReader, 'fieldnames'):
            # Python 2.5 fieldnames workaround. (http://bugs.python.org/issue3436)
            reader = UnicodeReader(csvfile, dialect, encoding=encoding, *args, **kwds)
            self.fieldnames = _stringify_list(reader.next(), reader.encoding)
        self.unicode_fieldnames = [_unicodify(f, encoding) for f in
                                   self.fieldnames]
        self.unicode_restkey = _unicodify(restkey, encoding)

    def next(self):
        row = csv.DictReader.next(self)
        result = dict((uni_key, row[str_key]) for (str_key, uni_key) in
                      izip(self.fieldnames, self.unicode_fieldnames))
        rest = row.get(self.restkey)
```

Comment: Please post the **full text** of the traceback. Also, please indicate which version of Python you are using.

Comment: Its likely utf=8 encoded. Try that.

Comment: @tdelaney I have tried with utf=8  and it's returning me this : "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 35: invalid continuation byte "

Comment: @MattDMo I have posted the full text of the traceback and I am using Python 2.7

Comment: You should be able to figure out the line and then `print repr(line)`. Post that and maybe we can guess. Are you on windows? Maybe it saved as a windows code page. I'm not sure how you got the file in the first place, but using `sys.stdout.encoding` may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ASCII codec can't encode character error during write to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939771/python-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-error-during-write-to-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python2, the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) does not support unicode. So you must pass in some kind of iterator object (such as a file) which only produces *byte-strings*.

This means that your code should look like this:

```
with open('tr.csv', 'rb') as fp:
    myClassif = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")
```

But note that the csv file **must** be encoded as UTF-8. If it's not, you will obviously need to convert it to UTF-8 first, in order for the code above to work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the traceback says *En*codeError, not DecodeError. It looks like the NaiveBayesClassifier is expecting ascii. Either make it accept Unicode, or, if this is OK for your application, replace non-ascii characters with '?' or something.

Comment: I have attached above the code from the library I am using,  should I change the " encoding = utf-8 " ?

Comment: How do you initialize your library? It accepts an `encoding` argument. Did you try setting it to latin1?

Comment: I am using a classifier provided by this library and I am just importing the library :from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob I have tried now using latin1 and same error. Is there an encoding which contains all the characters including special ones ?

Comment: Hmm. Can you convert the input data to UTF-8 once and for all, or does it keep changing?